# Importing Dataset into Prolog

Tags: csv, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to load a csv file and use it as a knowledge base in Prolog, but I do not know how to do that. I am using a file that has 100 lines and 43 rows. It should contain 20 attributes (you can choose the names for yourself).

I searched online where I could, but my task is much more complex than anything I was able to find

This is what I did so far, but I am trying to see the rows

```
:- use_module(library(csv)).

% Read the data from the CSV file
read_csv_file(File, Rows) :-
    csv_read_file(File, Rows, [skip_header_row(true)]).

% Entry point for the program
main :-
    % Open the CSV file
    open('data.csv', read, Stream),

    % Read the data from the file
    read_csv_file(Stream, Rows),

    % Close the file
    close(Stream),

    % Print the rows
    print_rows(Rows).

% Print the rows of the CSV file
print_rows([]).
print_rows([Row | Rest]) :-
    writeln(Row),
    print_rows(Rest).
```

Comment: You probably want to use library(csv), see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv, start with a small file and try to see if you can read all the rows, don't hesitate to post questions with a smaller scope and show the code you already wrote, you'll have more helpful answers

Comment: so after doing this (csv_read_file('GermanCredit-Dataset-100.csv').), what should I do in order to see all the rows?

Comment: Here in you only give one argument, the file, but in the documentation there must be at least two arguments, for the second one you can write Rows (with a capital). This is a variable that will be unified by prolog to contain a list of rows, as read from the file. You probably have to try smaller prolog exercises I guess to familarize yourself with the language (also, don't wrap in parentheses, this is `csv_read_file("file", Rows).`)

Comment: so what would be the full code for me to see all the 100 rows? I am still a bit confused

Comment: Reading a CSV file into a list is *one* line of code - see csv_read_file at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv - you can them loop through the data.

Comment: "a file that has 100 lines and 43 rows" why is no one commenting on this here, what does that even mean?

Comment: @TA_intern a CSV with quoted fields can have newlines in the data - could show as 100 lines in a text editor but only 43 records.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler do you know this is the case of OP or are you guessing?

Comment: @TA_intern - guessing a way rows/lines could plausibly differ. (If you want questions, does "attributes" mean the columns, and is it important that the file "has" 100 lines but "should have" 20 columns? Is it OP telling us to make up the names or is it OP's homework telling OP? Why make up names then use `skip_header_row`? Does this all mean OP is creating the file with 20 columns and made up header names? Then why not skip all this import stuff and make a Prolog source file and consult it? Why was "import csv" more complex than anything they could find online?). We'll probably never know.